# Using PHP variables in an HTML element class with Blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel and Blade on a small project and am trying to dynamically assign class names to generated elements in a for loop. However, the generated elements are generating literally, such as "`<div class='form_q' .$i>`".

```
@for($i = 0; $i < count($formdata['form2']); $i++)
  <div class='form_q'.$i>
    HTML::attributes('class')
    <div class='q'.$i.'-header'>
      <h1>{{ Form::label($formdata['form2']['q'.($i + 1)]['question'], $formdata['form2']['q'.($i + 1)]['type'], array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'))}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
@endfor
```

What's the proper syntax for concatenating a string and variable and assigning it to an class/attribute? Alternatively, what is the proper Blade syntax for generating a "div" element with an assigned class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Blade or PHP you want to print the output.

Ether surround the $i variables like `{{ $i }}` or like `<?php echo $i ?>`. Blade just converts back to PHP for example, `{{ }}` is converted into `<?php echo ?>`. Keep in mind that you're still using PHP when making Blade templates.

```
@for($i = 0; $i < count($formdata['form2']); $i++)
  <div class='form_q{{ $i }}'>
      HTML::attributes('class')
      <div class='q{{ $i }}-header'>
        <h1>{{ Form::label($formdata['form2']['q'.($i + 1)]['question'], $formdata['form2']['q'.($i + 1)]['type'], array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'))}}</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
@endfor
```

You should go over the Blade docs again. http://laravel.com/docs/templates

Answer (score 0):

I don't know laravel or blade, but I think you should use double curly brackets to echo a php variable, like this:

```
<div class='form_q'{{$i}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ $i }} = `<?php echo $i ?>`

Example for image BLADE with Array php

{!! Html::image( asset('**/profile/'.$u->foto**), 'Profile', array('class' => 'avatar;')) !!}